# C# conditions not working same for bool values

Tags: c#, csv-injection

I have a piece of code, in which I set `true` or `false` depending upon the conditions.

Below is that code

```
public bool HackerTextExistOrNot(string text)
    {
        bool flgValid = false;
        var attackChars = new char[] { '=', '+', '-', '@' };

        if(attackChars.Contains(text[0]))
        {
            flgValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            flgValid = true;
        }
        return flgValid;
    }
```

I have checked for both the bool conditions, but it always goes in `strReturnId` in main function.

Below is the code.

```
public static string SaveRecord(RRSOCSaving RRSOCSaving, string Indication)
        {
            string strReturnId = "";
            string strAppURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppUrl"].ToString();
            string strmail_Content = "";

            CommonDB commonObj = new CommonDB();

            GET_DATA_BY_STORE objGetData = new GET_DATA_BY_STORE();

            try
            {
                if (objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_CODE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STATE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.CITY) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SITE_STORE_FORMAT) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_SITENAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_MANAGER_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.MANAGER_MOBNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.EMP_NEAREST_STORE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SUPERVISOR_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SUPERVISOR_MOBNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NAME_ALIGNED_LPO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.LPO_MOBILENO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALPM_ALPO_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.AREA_MANAGER_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ZONAL_HEAD_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ZONAL_HEAD_NO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.DVR_IP_ADDRESS) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NEAREST_HOSP_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_ADDRESS) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_SPACE_SQFT) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.LAUNCH_DATE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.CST_TIN_NO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_EMAILID) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NO_OF_POS) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NO_OF_CAMERA) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.CAMERA_MODEL) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.FACILTY_TEAMNAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.FACILITY_TEAMNO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.LPA) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SLP_STATE_HEAD) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.UserName) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.CREATED_DATE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.UserName) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.LAST_UPDATED_DATE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ISACTIVE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.LATITUDE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.LONGITUDE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SLP_EMAILID) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ZONAL_ECNUMBER) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ZONAL_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.IS_STORE_IN_MALL) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.IS_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_AVAIL) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.IS_NIGHT_PATROL_PARTY_AVAIL) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.PATROL_PARTY_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.PATROL_PARTY_NO) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALPM_ALPO_EMAILID) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALIGNED_LPO_ECNUMBER) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.SLP_STATE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.FORMAT_GROUP) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALPM_NAME) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.ALPM_ECNUMBER))
                {
                    strReturnId = "Something went wrong due to malicious script attack..!!!";
                }
                else
                {

                    if (RRSOCSaving.ROLE_ASSIGNED == "SLP State Head")
                    {
                        bool blnState1 = Array.Exists(RRSOCSaving.ASSIGNED_STATE.ToString().ToUpper().Split(','), element => element == (RRSOCSaving.STATE).ToString().ToUpper());

                        if (blnState1)
                        {
                            strmail_Content = Get_Email_Content(RRSOCSaving.STORE_CODE, RRSOCSaving.UserName, Indication, RRSOCSaving.STATE, RRSOCSaving.SITE_STORE_FORMAT, RRSOCSaving.STORE_SITENAME);
                            //  SendEmail(RRSOCSaving.UserName, RRSOCSaving.STORE_CODE, RRSOCSaving.SLP_EMAILID, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NHQEmail"].ToString(), strmail_Content, Indication);
                            strReturnId = CommonDB.INSERT_INTO_RRSOC_INFO(RRSOCSaving, Indication);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strReturnId = "User can add data for " + RRSOCSaving.ASSIGNED_STATE + " only";
                        }
                    }
                    else if (RRSOCSaving.ROLE_ASSIGNED == "NHQ Admin")
                    {
                        strmail_Content = Get_Email_Content(RRSOCSaving.STORE_CODE, RRSOCSaving.UserName, Indication, RRSOCSaving.STATE, RRSOCSaving.SITE_STORE_FORMAT, RRSOCSaving.STORE_SITENAME);
                        // SendEmail(RRSOCSaving.UserName, RRSOCSaving.STORE_CODE, RRSOCSaving.SLP_EMAILID, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NHQEmail"].ToString(), strmail_Content, Indication);
                        strReturnId = CommonDB.INSERT_INTO_RRSOC_INFO(RRSOCSaving, Indication);
                        //strReturnId = "Record Saved Succesfully";
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return strReturnId;

        }
```

**UPDATE** I mean to say always in

`strReturnId = "Something went wrong due to malicious script attack..!!!";`

Comment: This question is a little confusing. You need an [mcve]

Comment: `if(attackChars.Contains(text[0]))` is this condition correct ?

Comment: @jophab: yes, its correct.!

Comment: Can u please share the value of `RRSOCSaving.STORE_CODE` ? Does any values really starts with the attackChars ?

Comment: Additionally, your code *isn't* a Javascript snippet, so please don't format it as if it were. Note that you still haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: @jophab: THe value is `HENTEST`

Comment: "it always goes in strReturnId" - what do you mean by that? Please edit your question to make it *much* clearer.

Comment: As an aside, your `if` statement and the local variable can all be replaced with `return attackChars.Contains(text[0]);`

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have updated the question. May be its much clearer now. It always goes in first condition of `strReturnId = "Something went wrong due to malicious script attack..!!!";` even if its true or false

Comment: This is definitely not the way to guard against injection attacks anyway. You should use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of `ToUpper`. And `catch { throw;` is just useless.

Comment: Your `HackerTextExistOrNot()` returns `true` if the string does NOT begin with any of  '=', '+', '-', '@'. So if the string doesn't contain any of those, the big `if` will enter its body. This seems to be the wrong way around.

Comment: @Charlieface: If any other way then please let me know.. Would try that way if its according to my requirement

Comment: @MatthewWatson: So how could I do that? any suggestion

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are doing with the text you need to check. Is it SQL, or is it HTML or what? To guard against injection, you either use proper parameterization, or you escape it. Checking for "bad" input is an exercise in futility

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's actually return !attackChars.Contains(text[0]);

Comment: @PalleDue: Whoops, yes, absolutely.

Comment: The question was last updated *before* my comment saying how it was unclear. It's still unclear, and it still doesn't have a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ok, See, I just want user to stop inserting some invalid characters.. SO for that I am implementing the code which I posted. Now that same code works same for both true and false condition which is wrong. I want to check and correct that.

Comment: "Now that same code works same for both true and false condition which is wrong" - I don't know what you mean by that. I suspect I *would* understand if you would just post a [mcve]. Hint: a minimal example wouldn't contain an `if` condition that had 76 lines of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your

> HackerTextExistOrNot

method returns true when hacker text does NOT exist. Instead of using flgValid just return attackChars.Contains(text[0]) and it should be working correctly.

One more thing - you are creating table each time entering this method, you might consider refactoring this code.

Comment: returning like `return attackChars.Contains(text[0]);` is going in `catch` block. giving error as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Piotr, help with the code. The current `return` is giving error.

Comment: try changing it to return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && attackChars.Contains(text[0]);

Comment: now I returned like this `return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && attackChars.Contains(text[0]));` but still getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure this line throws an exception? If so, then the only possibility is that attackChars is null. If it's not, the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: no this line doesn't throws any error, after this it goes to `if (objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STORE_CODE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.STATE) ||
                    objGetData.HackerTextExistOrNot(RRSOCSaving.CITY) ||` where it throws and goes to catch block

Comment: well, actually this line was supposed to be part of HackerTextExistOrNot method. So if it fails on these conditions then either objGetData is null or RRSOCSaving is null. If the exception is thrown further then it's not really part of this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238313/discussion-between-hud-and-piotr-wojsa).